# How do I resize one specific image in custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Please note that I am new to wordpress and I apologize in advance if I am asking a poorly formed question or am leaving out details. I will follow up with anything you need as an answerer.

Problem: I have an image that's spilling over the div, container, etc? (I'm also new to CSS) in Wordpress. Here is the image: [image]

I'd like it to fit in the image. Also note that the image shows another image when a mouse hovers over it. Strangely that image has no issues with resizing. I've tried a variety of solutions including.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain
}
```

And I've tried editing the image dimensions in the media page. Part of the problem is it's a custom theme. And custom themes are a little harder to work with when it comes to custom CSS (or so I've learned). Any suggestions on the matter are greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you have further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out custom CSS wasn't necessary. The image itself was actually formatted incorrectly. I didn't check that option because I thought to myself, "It couldn't possibly be that." Leaving this as a possible answer for people who've tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon. Please add more code so people can see how you've formatted the image.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

It may be best to make a div then place the image in it as a container.

```css
img {
        max-width: 100%;
}
    
.imagecontainer {
      width 50%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}

.imagewrapper {
      width 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagewrapper">
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/olSLV.png">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The missing semicolon was a typo. As for the div, I'm not sure where to edit that in wordpress. As I mentioned this is a custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

```html
.classname img {width:100%; height:auto;}

/*replace classname with your div class*/
```